# clarification of "this" keyword in Java

Tags: java, this

I have this code copied from Android developers website:

```
public class ExampleActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedValues) {
        ...
        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.corky);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    // Implement the OnClickListener callback
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // do something when the button is clicked
    }
    ...
}
```

I am wondering what exactly "this" keyword refers to? Does it refer to the class "ExampleActivity"? And in general how to find what "this" refers to?

Comment: Read here: https://smugjava.blogspot.in/2017/11/this-keyword-in-java.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It refers to the instance of `ExampleActivity` on which `onCreate()` has been called.

In general, from the [Java Language Specification, 15.8.3](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/j3TOC.html):

> The keyword this may be used only in the body of an instance method, instance initializer or constructor, or in the initializer of an instance variable of a class. If it appears anywhere else, a compile-time error occurs.
>
> When used as a primary expression, the keyword this denotes a value that is a reference to the object for which the instance method was invoked (§15.12), or to the object being constructed. The type of this is the class C within which the keyword this occurs. At run time, the class of the actual object referred to may be the class C or any subclass of C.

Answer (score 2):

`this` refers to the most inner class instance. In your example it refers to `ExampleActivity` which is of type `OnClickListener` which is passed in to `setOnClickListener`.

Answer (score 1):

> Within an instance method or a
>   constructor, `this` is a reference to
>   the current object — the object whose
>   method or constructor is being called.
>   You can refer to any member of the
>   current object from within an instance
>   method or a constructor by using `this`.

**Reference (from the Sun Java Tutorial):**

- [Using the this keyword](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)
- [Understanding Instance and Class
  Members](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Answer (score 1):

"this" is a reference to the current object.

In your case, it refers to an instance of the ExampleActivity class.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, 'this' refers to the instance of the enclosing class.